# Disable vertical scroll but keep scroll event

Tags: jquery, css, scroll, position

When users scroll the page, I want to slide down a div until it reaches it´s final position, then let the browser scroll as usual.

My first thought was just to reset the scrollTop inside the scroll event, like this:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    // 0 is the final position for `main`,
    // Initially set to -390px
    if(parseInt($('main').css('top')) < 0) {
        $(window).scrollTop(0); // <-------- nothing should happen

        // ... more stuff
    }
});
```

Works fine in Firefox. But when I test in Safari, it results in a horrible "bounce-effect".
Obviously because Safari first scrolls down and then sets the position back due to my `scrollTop(0)`.

Ok, another solution. Why not set `position: fixed` to `html` and `body`? Example:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if(parseInt($('main').css('top')) < 0) {
        $('html, body').css('position', 'fixed'); // <-------- next try

        // ... more stuff
    }
});
```

Got it! Works fine in Safari, let´s check Firefox and… nothing happens! Firefox fires the scroll-event exactly one time, until I set html and body to fixed.

So this is my question: how to avoid vertical scrolling cross-browser, without optical side effects AND still getting a scroll event?

Comment: Well there's technically no `scroll` event without scrolling... I'm assuming you're talking about scrolling via a mousewheel, right? Why not look into capturing `onmousewheel` instead? You'll have to note though, not everybody has a mousewheel.

Comment: Not only scrollwheel. Every action that would scroll down the whole page should be captured and "replaced" with my div sliding functionality. And there IS a scroll event, at least in one browser.